# Class DropboxAPI.DeltaPage<MD> - what is MD?

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to create a DeltaPage object using the Dropbox Core API. I should get this by calling delta which takes a cursor argument detailing past calls to delta (initially null).

Eclipse says DropboxAPI.DeltaPage is a raw type. References to generic type DropboxAPI.DeltaPage should be parameterized if I do this:

```
String deltaCursor = null; 
DeltaPage delta = mDBApi.delta(deltaCursor)
delta.cursor = deltaCursor;
```

And it suggests I change it to this:

```
String deltaCursor = null; 
DeltaPage<Entry> delta = mDBApi.delta(deltaCursor);
delta.cursor = deltaCursor;
```

I don't understand :-( An Entry object is returned when you call the metadata for a file or folder. As in here:

```
Entry myDBFolder = null;
myDBFolder = mDBApi.metadata(params[0], 0, null, true, null);
```

(Where params[0] is the string at 0 in my params string array of dropbox file paths.)

Why do I need to put Entry after DeltaPage? Why is the object DeltaPage< MD> ? What is MD? The [javadoc](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4-docs/index.html) is not very illuminating for me but maybe I am being stupid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata call directly returns the metadata for the requested item, but the delta call returns pages that contain multiple metadata entries (since delta needs to be able to tell you about many different items.) The DeltaPage docs explain that the MD is metadata:

https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.DeltaEntry.html